# undefined variable multiple errors

Tags: php, smarty

I am currently developing a website and I keep getting 2 errors in my register page. These are the errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: error in C:\xampp\htdocs\olympus\register.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined variable: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\olympus\register.php on line 36
```

And these are the code lines they refer to:

```
line 35 - $smarty->assign('error',$error);

line 36 - $smarty->assign('message',$message);
```

I've double checked everything and I can't find why I have those errors.
Can someone help me with these one, please?

Edit: this is the complete register.php file so far.

```
<?php

require_once 'smarty.php';

if($_POST) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confirm = $_POST['confirm'];
    if($password != $confirm) {
        $error = 'Passwords do not match!'; 
    } else {
        require_once 'config.php';      // our database settings
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)
            or die('Error connecting to mysql');
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        list($count) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        if($count >= 1) { 
            $error = 'that username is taken.';
        } else {
            $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
                mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']),
                mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)));
            mysql_query($query);            
            $userID = mysql_insert_id($conn);
            require_once 'stats.php';
            setStat('atk',$userID,'5');
            setStat('def',$userID,'5');         
            setStat('mag',$userID,'5');
            $message = 'Congratulations, you registered successfully!';
        }
    }   
}
$smarty->assign('error',$error);
$smarty->assign('message',$message);
$smarty->display('register.tpl');

?>
```

Comment: Doesn't "undefined variable" clearly describe what's going on? What exactly did you double check?

Comment: Error message seems clear...can you publish your php code to help us ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your errors clearly describe whats going on:

`$error` and `$message` are not set. Thats all.

You should at least initialize them before that lines:

```
$error = $message = '';
```

or

```
$error = $message = array();
```

And also, btw: its just notice, not syntax error, so can avoid that errors to not show with this code at the beginning:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

**EDITED:**

If `$_POST` is not setted (form is not sent), it will not go inside than condition. So then your two variables are undefined. So just pre-define them at the beginning. Change your code to this:

```
<?php

require_once 'smarty.php';

$error = $message = ''; // THIS IS ADDED HERE...

if($_POST) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confirm = $_POST['confirm'];
    if($password != $confirm) {
        $error = 'Passwords do not match!'; 
    } else {
        require_once 'config.php';      // our database settings
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)
            or die('Error connecting to mysql');
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        list($count) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        if($count >= 1) { 
            $error = 'that username is taken.';
        } else {
            $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
                mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']),
                mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)));
            mysql_query($query);            
            $userID = mysql_insert_id($conn);
            require_once 'stats.php';
            setStat('atk',$userID,'5');
            setStat('def',$userID,'5');         
            setStat('mag',$userID,'5');
            $message = 'Congratulations, you registered successfully!';
        }
    }   
}
$smarty->assign('error',$error);
$smarty->assign('message',$message);
$smarty->display('register.tpl');

?>
```

Or just move this:

```
$smarty->assign('error',$error);
$smarty->assign('message',$message);
```

inside that condition `if($_POST) {` at the end.

Comment: ive posted the complete code. can u help me with the missing part please?

Comment: Edited. You can have a look.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. i'm just starting and learning it all by myself. It's hard sometimes when little things like these appear.